# Compiling using latexmk from a different directory?

Tags: pdftex, input, latexmk

I have 2 questions:

1) If I am in a directory `parent`, how can I compile a PDF file from a `main.tex` file that is in directory `parent/subfolder/subfolder1/` to that same last location?

I've tried `latexmk -pdf subfolder/subfolder/main.tex`, and it does work, but it compiles all auxiliary files and the resulting PDF file to the directory from where the script was run (`parent`). Is there any way to make it output the aux files and the PDF to the directory where the target `main.tex` is located, while still running this command from `parent`?

2) My `main.tex` makes a reference to a file located in a folder on a different directory, namely: `../commands/command.tex` . Using `\input{../commands/command.tex}` and compiling from that same directory works, however once I am in directory `parent` and try to do the same thing then I get the message `! LaTeX Error: File ../commands/command.tex' not found.` How can I successfully import this file and compile it from `parent`?

Here a simplified version of my `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{../commands/command.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{simple_equation}
    \alpha = \sqrt{ \beta }
\end{equation}

\test % my defined command

\end{document}
```

and my `command.tex` file:

```
\newcommand{\test}{dummy text}
```

Please bear in mind the folder structure is:

```
parent
       subfolder
                subfolder1
                          main.tex
                commands 
                          command.tex
```

And I would like to compile main.tex from directory `parent`

Comment: Maybe `latexmk -pdf -cd subfolder/subfolder/main.tex` (note the **-cd**) does the trick?

Comment: On linux systems this problem can be solved by a `#!/bin/bash` script than runs pdflatex or latexmk or whatever command you like from any directory (I have done it on mine). I think it works on mac too because it is a linux too (but never had one and I am not sure)... As far as I know windows supports linux commands by a way these days... You could ask there if you are a windows user

Comment: @Daniel, so simple! Thank you, that worked perfectly. koleygr, thanks for the suggestion, I tried this approach after posting this question, but I think Daniel's simple answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As was already mentioned in a comment, the `-cd` option to latexmk does exactly what you request

```
latexmk -pdf -cd subfolder/subfolder/main.tex
```

Answer (score 1):

**On linux systems (may be mac too)** you can create a `#!/bin/bash` script (Let's name it myLTXRun.sh and save it on the main.tex's directory):

This script will contain the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND1="cd /path/of/main/latex/file"
COMMAND2="latexmk main.tex"
echo "Running:"$COMMAND1
$COMMAND1
echo "Running:"$COMMAND2
$COMMAND2
```

Then you will give the required permissions to the .sh file with the command
(from the directory of the main.tex file):

```
chmod +775 myLTXRun.sh
```

Then from any directory you can run the command:

```
sh /path/to/mainFile/dir/myLTXRun.sh
```

(Tested on debian GNU/Linux)

**On windows 10** you can use exactly the same steps after installing the Windows subsystem for linux: [here are instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide)

(I haven't test it yet!)

From a command prompt the last command have to be replaced with:

```
bash -c "sh /path/to/mainFile/dir/myLTXRun.sh"
```

Comment: The method works for any kind of supported tex/latex etc commands as far as I can understand. I tested it with pdflatex.