# Missing images when compiling with a script

Tags: compiling

What might be the issue or what can affect the compiling of my latex files when run in terminal or from a script?

So I have this `.tex` file and compiling it from TexLive on my laptop and it's going fine, but when I run the command from terminal the images are not set in their place, I'll need to run the command again and then the file gets rewritten with the images in place.

PS I also need to run the code using `batchmode` if this is the problem, how is it safer to run my code without having the terminal popping questions and waiting for me to give it input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If a script or batch code sets its home directory to something other than the invocation directory, then the set of tex support files (images, local styles, or includes, etc) may be different or not available, as compared to a local execution in that directory.

Comment: is the a way to over come this issue and yet be able to have an output directory for the files ? @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: You could either have the script copy the contents of the local directory to the batch-execution directory prior to compilation, or else perform the the compilation process in the local directory and only have the completed result moved to the batch-specified directory.

Comment: ok thanks mate, ill try both options and check what will suit me best, ill reply here if it worked thanks again :) @StevenB.Segletes

Comment: You can take a look to my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391868/120578 I think it is the second way of @StevenB.Segletes