# Trying to build a latex document with latexmk and additional tex files in subdirectory

Tags: include, latexmk

I am trying to build a complex latex document (at least it's complex for me). The directory structure looks like this:

```
- bat.tex
- packages.tex
- {other tex files}.tex
- content
-- {chapter folders}
--- chapter.tex
-- abstract.tex
```

Till now I built the document with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
start=`date +%s`

echo ----------------------------
echo Generating Documentation
echo ----------------------------

echo Generating PDF \(pass 1\)
lualatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode bat.tex > /dev/null

echo Generating Bibliography
biber bat > /dev/null

echo Generating Glossaries
makeglossaries bat > /dev/null

echo Finishing PDF
lualatex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode bat.tex > /dev/null

end=`date +%s`

runtime=$((end-start))

echo $runtime s
```

Which works great. But I would like to build it with latexmk.

So I wrote this `.latexmkrc`

```
$latex = 'latex  %O --shell-escape %S'; 
$pdflatex = 'lualatex  %O --shell-escape %S; 
$pdf_mode = 4; $bib_program = 'biber';

$out_dir = 'build';
```

The problem now is, that it does not find the `.aux` files from the `content` subdirectory. I found this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include) which does not have any good solution. Since it is rather old I wanted to ask if there is a fix for my problem or another good solution.

Also will my `.latexmkrc` file work with `biber`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391998

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL my main.tex is not in a subdirectory, but the files I include in it.

Comment: you can place the output of the command `tree`?

Comment: A couple of side issues: 1. You don't need to set `$bib_program` in `.latemkrc`. It will have no effect, since `latexmk` automatically determines whether to run `bibtex` or `biber`.  2. Your line `$pdflatex = 'lualatex  %O --shell-escape %S;` should be `$lualatex = 'lualatex  %O --shell-escape %S;`.

Comment: Are are using `\include` in your document? If not there should be no problem with `.aux` files in the `content` subdirectory. You say that "it does not find the `.aux` files from the `content` subdirectory". A problem you could encounter is that lualatex or pdflatex may say that it cannot **write** to the `.aux` file(s), which is not the same.  You can solve the problem by creating ahead of time a content subdirectory in the build directory.  (`latexmk` does this, but only after the first compilation, which is too late to prevent you seeing an error. Later compilations should go fine.)

Comment: @JohnCollins If I exchange the line`$pdflatex` as you test, I get the error `The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.` In my main tex file I got the first lines `%!TEX TS-program = lualatex`

Comment: It looks like you are correct with your second comment. It says, that it can't write into the file. Is there something to create the needed folder structure ahead of time? I only found some hackish solutions.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of @JohnCollins I was able to get it working:

.latexmk

```
sub createFolderStructure{
   system("bash ./createFolderStructure.sh");
}

createFolderStructure();

$latex = 'latex  %O --shell-escape %S';
$pdflatex = 'lualatex  %O --shell-escape %S --output-directory=build --aux-directory=build';
$pdf_mode = 4;

$out_dir = 'build';
```

createFolderStructure.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

find ./content -type d > folder_list.txt

mkdir -p build
cd build
cat ../folder_list.txt | xargs mkdir -p
rm ../folder_list.txt
```

With this there is no initial error with creating the folder structure under the `build` folder.